# Why is my method not emptying the ArrayList<Card>?

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm trying to empty the ArrayList hand, so that a new round can be played. I'm not sure why my for loop isn't emptying the "hand" and instead only removing the first card in the hand. Here's my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class Game {

        private Deck aDeck;
        private InputReader reader;
        private ArrayList<Card> hand;
        private String commandChoice;
        private int handValue;

        /**
         * Method to run the game. 
         * First while loop will run until the player chooses "no" for another round.
         * Second while look will keep running until the player chooses to stand, has 21 or     busts.
         * the last while loop is to make sure that the player chooses either "Hit" or "Stand". If neither is choosen, it will keep requesting it.
         */
        public void Play(){
            int playerPoints = 0;
            int totalRounds = 0;
            commandChoice = "";
            hand = new ArrayList<Card>();
            reader = new InputReader();

            intro();
            aDeck = new Deck();
            aDeck.loadDeck();
            aDeck.shuffle();
            aDeck.shuffle();

            while(anotherRound() == false){
                dealCard();
                dealCard();
                report();

                playTurn();
                totalRounds ++;

                emptyHand();
                endRound();
                anotherRound();

            }
            System.out.println("Player Points: " + playerPoints);
            System.out.println("Total Rounds: " + totalRounds);
        }

        /**
         * intro message to player
         */
        private void intro(){
            System.out.println("Welcome to 1451 Blackjack!");
            System.out.println("You will start with two cards.");
            System.out.println("You will be prompted to 'hit' or 'stand' 'hit' means you want another card, 'stand' not.");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("You are trying to get Blackjack with exactly 21 points.");

        }
        /**
        * deals a card to the player
        */
        private void dealCard(){
        int deckSize = aDeck.deckSize();
        if(deckSize == 0){
            System.out.println("Time for some more cards");
            aDeck.loadDeck();
            aDeck.shuffle();
            aDeck.shuffle();
        } else {
        Card tempCard = aDeck.takeCard();
        hand.add(tempCard);
        }
    }

    /**
     * calculates the hand value of the player
     * @return handValue
     */
    private int getHandValue(){
        handValue = 0;
        for(Card eachCard : hand) {
            int tempValue = eachCard.getValue();
            handValue = handValue + tempValue;
        }
        return handValue;
    }

    /**
     * displays contents of hand
     */
        private void showHand(){
            System.out.println("Your cards:"); 
            for(Card eachCard : hand) {
                    System.out.println(eachCard.getDescription()+ 
                                    " of " + eachCard.getSuit());
             }
        }

        private void emptyHand(){
            for(int count = 0; count < hand.size(); count++) {
                 hand.remove(count);
             }
        }
```

Obviously somethings broken with my code in the "emptyHand()" method, but what am I missing?! Driving me insane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by which index is selected for removal *and* a changing list size. In addition to "not clearing" the list, such could could also have resulted in an IndexOutOfBounds exception.

Consider a hand of `{A, B, C, D, E}` and the loop flow goes like the following; which can also be seen by stepping through the loop with a debugger..

```
i      size()    result after remove(i)
-----  --------  ----------------------
0      5         {B, C, D, E}
1      4         {B, D, E}
2      3         {B, D}
3      2         -> done  (2 cards left!)
```

The simple fix is to use [`hand.clear()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clear()) although other solutions include iterating through the indices backwards or always "popping" the end.

```
for (int i = hand.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   hand.remove(i);
}

while (hand.size() > 0) {
   hand.remove(hand.size() - 1);
   // or hand.remove(0); but this causes bad complexity bounds on an ArrayList
}
```

Create a similar table as above to justify that these approaches work.

Comment: Thank you, your answer makes complete sense with what I was attempting to do. Could I have done something like:


private void emptyHand(){
            int handSize = hand.size();
            'for(int count = 0; count < handSize; count++) {'
                 'hand.remove(count);'
             }
        }

Comment: @Wulf That only fixes the `size()` changing issue. The other issue is that `remove()` *shifts* the elements (and thus their positions) within the List. This is why backward iteration or removing a fixed head index (although this is bad here) is also important.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore this question, I was unaware of the ArrayList Command "Clear" which does exactly what I was trying to do.